# How do I get data between table in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table and I want to insert some something between two rows via collapse toggle. Is it possible if so how?

So basically I want the "Hello" in between two rows of the table.

Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/DKAi7ZLu6B

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">First</th>
  <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>@fat</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

      <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
  $('.insert-here').toggle();;
});
```

```css
.insert-here {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">First</th>
  <th class="insert-here" scope="col">Hello</th>
  <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td class="insert-here"></td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td class="insert-here"></td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>@fat</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Maybe this helps you?

Comment: There's this issue now. I don't know if you can help. Because I'm using a DIV structure I can't use DataTables and if I want to use it either I have to delete or change DIV structure. Is there any workaround that DataTables can be dodged?

Comment: I found this : the "dom" setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377563/i-want-to-use-div-structure-in-datatables-instead-of-table-is-it-possible